# For a proper traffic analysis between 2 computers, does wireshark need to be on a third laptop or just one of the two?

Tags: network, wireshark

Looking at a situation where two machines use a secure communication protocol like this:

Machine (or a VM) A <--------> Machine (or a VM) B

and I want to use Wireshark to capture the traffic between the two machines that are on the same network to see if it's really secure. Which of these is the correct scenario, or does it really matter as long as Wireshark is on the same network?

Scenario 1:   Machine A <---- Machine C + wireshark ----> Machine B
Scenario 2:   Machine A + wireshark <---------> Machine B

My understanding was that Wireshark will look at traffic that's dedicated to its MAC address or network card. This means it matters and wireshark should be placed in Scenario 1, otherwise in scenario 2 Wireshark will be able to see traffic in clear!

Comment: It depends on which network Wireshark is listening on and what protocol is used. In scenario 2: In case of a VPN it could listen on the hardware adapter (and should only see encrypted traffic) or on the virtual network adapter (should see non-encrypted traffic).

Answer (score 1):

For your two scenarios:

**Scenario 1**:

```
               wireshark box
                     |
machine A -- [network device] -- machine B
```

***Note**: machines can be bare metal or VMs. The [network device] can be physical or simulated/software defined.*

If the `network device` is a [hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub), then wireshark will be able to sniff all network traffic flowing between `machine A` and `machine B`.

If the `network device` is a [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), then `wireshark box` will need to use an active attack (either on the switch or the other machines) in order get the traffic.

The network card of the box where wireshark runs, should be in [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) (accept all traffic, even traffic that is not intented for wireshark's box).

**Scenario 2**:

```
machine A + wireshark -- [network device] -- machine B
```

Here the `network device` does not play any role because wireshark uses the same network interface as `machine A` and, as such, can sniff all traffic flowing through it.

To answer your question, whether wireshark can see the traffic in clear text or not, depends on whether encryption is employed and the encryption's type/setup.

For example, even in scenario 2 wireshark won't be able to see TLS protected traffic in clear text (as you presume in your question), because TLS is point-to-point between applications; this means that traffic reaches the target applications encrypted and is decrypted by the applications themselves.

Comment: As Spyros answered, scenario 2 is the easiest and most practical. If you are running Machines A & B as VM's on the same host, then running packet capture on the HOST works without having to deal with switch issues.